# Fourier transform of the distribution PV $\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I need to find the fourier transform of $f =$ *PV* $\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) $ which is defined as 
\begin{align}
           PV \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)(\varphi) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\varepsilon} \left( \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \right) dx 
\end{align}
 Let $\hat{f}$ denote Fourier transform of $f$. We know that $\langle \hat f,\varphi\rangle= \langle f,\hat \varphi\rangle$ where $\varphi$ is in Schwartz class , $S(\mathbb R)$.       $\\$
                   My attempt is as follows 
\begin{align}
\langle \hat f,\varphi\rangle 
= \langle f,\hat \varphi\rangle
& = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\varepsilon} \left( \frac{\hat\varphi(x)}{x} \right) dx \\&
= \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\varepsilon} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\xi)e^{ix\xi}d\xi\right)  dx \\&
  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\xi)\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\varepsilon} \left( \frac{e^{ix\xi}}{x} \right) dx d\xi
\\&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \varphi(\xi)\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\left( \frac{e^{ix\xi}}{x}\right)dx+\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty}\left( \frac{e^{ix\xi}}{x}\right)dx\right)d\xi. 
\end{align}
I am stuck here. I intituvely expect something like Heaviside function coming out of limit process and integration because  of presence of $\frac{1}{x}$.
 Any help will be deeply acknowledged.

Comment: Maybe you can use that $PV \left(\frac1x\right) = \ln'$ or that $x \, PV \left(\frac1x\right) = 1$ (as distribution)?

Comment: @RahulRajuPattar Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $u = PV\left(\frac1x\right)$. Then $xu = 1$. Now $\hat 1 = 2\pi \, \delta$ so we have
$$
\langle 2\pi \, \delta, \phi \rangle
= \langle \hat 1, \phi \rangle
= \langle \widehat{xu}, \phi \rangle
= \langle xu, \hat\phi \rangle
= \langle u, x \hat\phi \rangle
= \langle u, -i \widehat{\phi'} \rangle
= \langle -i \hat u, \phi' \rangle
= \langle i (\hat u)', \phi \rangle
$$

Thus, $i(\hat u)' = 2\pi \, \delta$ which gives $\hat u(\xi) = -i\pi \operatorname{sign}(\xi) + C$. But since $u$ is odd so is also $\hat u$ which forces $C = 0$.

Comment: Please, can you explain why $\langle -i \hat u, \phi' \rangle
= \langle i (\hat u)', \phi \rangle$?

Comment: @brt22. That directly follows by the definition of distributional derivative,
$\langle u', \phi \rangle = - \langle u, \phi' \rangle.$
Just apply it to $i \hat u$ and you get the equality in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $xp.v.\frac{1}{x} = 1$.
If $\delta$ is Dirac's delta function as a distribution then for all test functions, $\varphi$,
$$\bigg\langle \hat{\delta}, \varphi\bigg\rangle = \bigg\langle \delta, \hat{\varphi}\bigg\rangle = \hat{\varphi}(0) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi (x) dx = \bigg\langle 1, \varphi\bigg\rangle$$
Thus $\hat{\delta}$ = 1.

In order to deduce the Fourier transform of $1$ in the sense of distributions consider:

$\bigg\langle \hat{1}, \varphi\bigg\rangle = \bigg\langle 1, \hat{\varphi}\bigg\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{\varphi} (x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{2i\pi 0 x}\hat{\varphi} (x) dx = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\hat{\varphi}(0) = \varphi(0) = \bigg\langle \delta, \varphi\bigg\rangle$

Thus $\hat{1} = \delta$.

Now, using properties of derivatives of distributions and Fourier transforms of derivatives of functions:

$$ \bigg\langle \delta, \varphi\bigg\rangle = \bigg\langle \hat{1}, \varphi\bigg\rangle = \bigg\langle \mathcal{F}(xp.v.\frac{1}{x}), \varphi\bigg\rangle = 
\bigg\langle xp.v.\frac{1}{x}, \hat{\varphi}\bigg\rangle = \bigg\langle p.v.\frac{1}{x}, x\hat{\varphi}\bigg\rangle = 
\bigg\langle p.v.\frac{1}{x}, x \frac{\hat{\varphi '}}{2i\pi x}\bigg\rangle$$
(In the last equality we use the fact that $\mathcal{F}(f^{(k)}(\xi)) = (2i\pi \xi)^{(k)})\hat{f}(\xi)$.) 
$$= \bigg\langle p.v.\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{2i\pi } \hat{\varphi '}\bigg\rangle 
= \bigg\langle \frac{1}{2i\pi } p.v.\frac{1}{x}, \hat{\varphi '}\bigg\rangle 
= \bigg\langle \frac{1}{2i\pi } \mathcal{F}(p.v.\frac{1}{x}), \varphi '\bigg\rangle 
= \bigg\langle -\frac{1}{2i\pi } \big(\mathcal{F}(p.v.\frac{1}{x})\big)', \varphi \bigg\rangle $$
$$\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2i\pi } \big(\mathcal{F}(p.v.\frac{1}{x})\big)' = \delta$$

$H$ is the Heaviside function that is $0$ on $(-\infty, 0)$, $\frac{1}{2}$ on $0$, and $1$ on $(0, \infty)$. The derivative of $H$ in the sense of distributions is $\delta$. Thus we have:

$$ \mathcal{F}(p.v.\frac{1}{x}) = -2i\pi H + C$$

Since $p.v.\frac{1}{x}$ is odd, $\mathcal{F}(p.v.\frac{1}{x})$ is odd, and thus $-2i\pi H + C$ is an odd distribution. 
Thus the function describing the distribution, $-2i\pi H(x) + C$ is odd. 
That means $-2i\pi H(x) + C = -(-2i\pi H(-x) + C) = 2i\pi H(-x) - C$.

If $x$ is positive, $H(x) = 1, H(-x) = 0$, and we have $C = i\pi.$

If $x$ is negative, $H(x) = 0, H(-x) = 1$, and we have $C = i\pi.$

If $x$ is 0, $H(x) = H(-x) = H(0) =  \frac{1}{2}$, and we have $C = i\pi.$

Thus $\mathcal{F}(p.v.\frac{1}{x}) = -2i\pi H + i\pi$.

Note, $-2i\pi H + i\pi = -i\pi sgn$, where $sgn$ is the sign function, based on how we defined $H$.

Comment: next time choose recent unanswered questions or those for which your answer isn't the same as md2perpe:)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my method is virtually the same as md2perpe but it seems that he normalized his functions a little differently to get the Fourier transform in the sense of distributions of 1 = 2pi delta instead of just delta, which can be confusing because it seems contradictory on the surface (even though it's the same). Similar differences appear when taking the derivative of Fourier transforms. I hope that my answer provides more context and helps clarify the jargon.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're off by a minus sign in your definition of the Fourier transform. Accounting for this, you can then make a change of variables in your first $dx$ integral and combine the two $\epsilon$ limits as one:

\begin{align}
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\xi)\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} -\frac{e^{ix\xi}-e^{-ix\xi}}{x} dx\right)d\xi \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\xi)\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( -2i\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x\xi}{x} dx\right)d\xi \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\xi) (-2i) \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\text{sign}(\xi) \right) d\xi \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\varphi(\xi) \Big( -i\pi\,\text{sign}(\xi)\Big)d\xi \\
&= \langle F,\varphi \rangle,
\end{align}

where $F(\xi) = -i\pi\,\text{sign} \xi$. But now this means that $\widehat{PV(\frac{1}{x})} = -i\pi\,\text{sign} \xi$ as a distribution, since it's what you are integrating $\varphi$ against.

Comment: Thank you. I have followed the definition of Fourier transform as given in  Strichartz's Guide to distribution theory.

Comment: @patch Why do you assert that the OP was "off by a minus sign?"  The kernel of the FT can be $e^{ikx}$ or $e^{-ikx}$.  Which have you assumed?

Comment: @patch You have tacitly brought the limit inside the integral.  This needs to be justified and is an important part of the evaluation.  I provided the justification in my posted solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that the OP was attempting, but was not addressed in the currently posted answers.  Moreover, the interchange of integrals and the interchange of the limit with the integral need to be justified.  In the following we provide a way forward with justification.  To that end, we proceed.**

---

Your approach is formally on target.  Let the distribution $f$ be given by $f(x)=\text{PV}\left(\frac1x\right)$.  Then certainly we have

$$\begin{align} \langle \mathscr{F}\{f\},\phi \rangle&=\langle f, \mathscr{F}\{\phi\}\rangle\\\\
&=\text {PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathscr{F}\{\phi\}(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+\\L\to \infty}\int_{\varepsilon\le|x|\le L}\frac1x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(k)e^{ikx}\,dk\,dx\tag1\\\\
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+\\L\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) \int_\varepsilon^L \frac{2i\sin(kx)}{x}\,dx\,dk\tag2\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(k) i\pi \text{sgn}(k) \,dk\tag3\\\\
&=\langle i\pi \text{sgn}, \phi \rangle
\end{align}$$

So, we find that in distribution,

$$\mathscr{F}\{f\}=i\pi \text{sgn}$$

---

---

**NOTES:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, Fubini-Tonelli applies since $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$.  To see this, we note that since $\phi \in \mathbb{S}$, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\phi(k)e^{ikx}|\,dk=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\phi(k)|\,dk<\infty$.  Hence, the interated integral $\int_{\varepsilon<|x|<L}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\phi(k)e^{ikx}|\,dk<\infty$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem applies.  To see this, note that $\left|\phi(k)\int_\varepsilon^L \frac{2i \sin(kx)}{x}\,dx\right|\le |\phi(k)\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$ and is uniformly bounded by a function that is independent of $\varepsilon$ and $L$.  And inasmuch as $\phi\in\mathbb{S}$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\phi(k)|\,dk<\infty$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem is applicable.

Comment: There is something a bit askew here, since the PV functional is _odd_, so its Fourier transform will also be odd. The Heaviside function is not...  Some constant lost in the computation?

Comment: @paulgarrett The PV functional is odd.  And its FT is odd.  What is askew about that?

Comment: Well, if $H$ is $0$ to the left, and $1$ to the right, that's not quite "odd". Or do you mean "$H$" to be $-1$ to the left, and $+1$ to the right, or some other variant? That's all I'm asking about...

Comment: @paulgarrett Fixed.  Appreciate the heads up.

Comment: :) ... that's what I imagine you intended... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Unsure why I wrote $H$.  I am an idiot.

Comment: Aren't we all? :) ... though some of us are more photogenic idiots than others? :)

Comment: Yes indeed. ;-)

Comment: @RahulRajuPattar Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @MarkViola Why in (1) you wrote the definition of the inverse of Fourier transform while in symbol is of the Fourier Transform? are you defining the Fourier Transform with the kernel of positive exponent of the exponential function?

Comment: @Mr.Proof Yes, that is how I have defined the FT here.  And it is perfectly OK as long as we are consistent with how we define the FT pair.