# How to evaluate the Fourier sine transform of $1/x^3$

Tags: fourier-transform

With the help of Maple, I have get the Fourier sine transform of $1/x^3,$ which is defined as $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x\omega)}{x^3}d x.$
And  the output Maple given is

```
with(inttrans):
fouriersin(1/x^3,x,omega);
-sqrt(2)*sqrt(Pi)*omega^2/4
```

But I do not know how Maple calculated this. So I try to evaluate it by hand: By integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x\omega)}{x^3}d x\\
=&\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\left(\left(\sin(x\omega)\frac{x^{-2}}{-2}-\omega\cos(x\omega)\frac{x^{-1}}{-2(-1)}\right)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=+\infty}+\int_0^{+\infty}(-1)\omega^2\frac{\sin(x\omega)}{2x}d x\right).
\end{align*}
But it is clear that the function $\sin(x\omega)\frac{x^{-2}}{-2}-\omega\cos(x\omega)\frac{x^{-1}}{-2(-1)}$ is not convergent as $x\to 0$ from right. We known that, by Dirichlet integral, noting $x>0,$
\begin{gather*}
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x\omega)}{x}d x=\frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{gather*}
Thus, if we can show that
\begin{gather*}\tag{$\star$}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\sin(x\omega)\frac{x^{-2}}{-2}-\omega\cos(x\omega)\frac{x^{-1}}{-2(-1)}\right)=0,
\end{gather*}
then we arrive at $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x\omega)}{x^3}d x=-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\omega^2}{4}.$$
But $(\star)$ is not true. So I think that we can not use ordinary method of integration by parts to this integral. Now what should I do? Or can someone give me some hints or references.

PS: This problem comes out of the 5th exercise on page 323 of Weinberger's book A First Course in Partial Differential Equations with Complex Variables and Transform Methods, 1995.

Comment: The integral diverges due to the sharp singularity at $x=0$.

Comment: @MarkViola: Yes, the integral is divergent according to the classical definition of improper integral. But why Maple gives the result. Maybe it uses a different definition, for instance, by distribution (generalized function).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+sin+transform+of+%281%2Fx%5E3%29 gives a result as well.

Comment: @VividKraig: Because MMA and Maple use the same definition of Fourier sine transform.

Comment: @MarkViola: If put this as a distribution, which space of test function should I  take? If I take $C^{\infty}_c((0,+\infty)),$ then the desired result follows directly, for the boundary integral vanished. Can you give some references on distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(\omega)$ be given by

$$F(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x^3}\,dx$$

Clearly, this integral diverges for $\omega \ne0$ due to the sharp singularity at $x=0$.  However, we can give a distributional interpretation to $F(\omega)$.

---

---

Denote by $F_\varepsilon(\omega)$ the integral

$$ F_\varepsilon(\omega)=\text{Re}\left(\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{(x+i\varepsilon)^3}\,dx\right)\tag1$$

Then, application of integration by parts twice to the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
F_\varepsilon(\omega)&=-\frac12\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\text{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{\omega^2\sin(\omega x)}{x+i\varepsilon}\,dx\right)\tag2
\end{align}$$

Letting $\varepsilon\to 0$ in $(2)$, we find that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}F_\varepsilon(\omega)=-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}\text{sgn}(\omega)\omega^2$$

We interpret $F(\omega)$ as the distributional limit of $(2)$.  That is, for a suitable test function $\phi(\omega)$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \phi,F\rangle &=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)F\varepsilon(\omega)\,d\omega\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(\omega)\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}\omega^2\text{sgn}(\omega)\right)\,d\omega\\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, in distribution

$$\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x^3}\,dx=-\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}\omega^2\text{sgn}(\omega)$$

Comment: You have only shown the limit for $\phi'' \in S,$ not for general $\phi \in S$. You can therefore only conclude equality modulo $\{ ax+b \mid a,b \in \mathbb{C} \}.$

Comment: $g(x) = e^{-x^2} \in S$ but no primitive function of $g$ is in $S$ since the primitive cannot tend to $0$ for both $x \to \infty$ and $x \to -\infty.$

Comment: That's correct, $ax+b$ is NOT a Schwartz space function. But it is a tempered distribution. That's what I meant although it wasn't clear. From your calculations you cannot conclude that $F(\omega) = - \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4} \omega^2 \operatorname{sgn}(\omega)$ but only that 
$$F(\omega) = - \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4} \omega^2 \operatorname{sgn}(\omega) + ax +b$$
for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}.$

Comment: I made an error, it should of course be $ \cdots + a\omega + b.$

Comment: Take $\phi'' \in S.$ Then 
$$
\langle x, \phi'' \rangle 
= - \langle 1, \phi' \rangle 
= \langle 0, \phi \rangle
= 0
= \langle 0, \phi'' \rangle
.
$$
Can we conclude that $x = 0$ in $S'$?

Comment: $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} x^{-3}1_{|x|>\epsilon}$ doesn't converge in the sense of distributions.   You need first to explain to the OP that we need a distribution agreeing with $x^{-3}$ on $\Bbb{R}^*$, for example $$<T,\phi>=\int_R \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)-\phi'(0)x-1_{|x|<1}\phi''(0) x^2  /2}{x^3}dx$$ Then $x^3T=1$, $\hat{T}''' = c\delta$ so $\hat{T}=c \xi^2 1_{\xi > 0}/2+P$ with $P$ a degree 2 polynomial that we deduce from the real oddness  of $T$ @md2perpe

Comment: My comment  is clear, we need a distribution, you don't have any distribution.

Comment: @reuns I've edited considerably and have changed the interpretation of the object $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x^3}\,dx$.  When you have a moment, I'd enjoy hearing your thoughts.  I hope that you are staying healthy and safe my friend.

Answer (score 3):

Rewriting the sine transform as a Fourier transform, $\frac{1}{x^3}$ as $-\frac12(\frac1x)''$ and interpreting $\frac1x$ as the principial value distribution, we get
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^3} \sin \omega x \, dx 
= \frac12 \left( \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3} \sin \omega x \, dx 
+ \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{x^3} \sin \omega x \, dx \right) 
= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3} \sin \omega x \, dx \\
= - \frac12 \operatorname{Im} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^3} e^{-i\omega x} \, dx 
= - \frac14 \operatorname{Im} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)'' e^{-i\omega x} \, dx
= \frac14 \omega^2 \operatorname{Im} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} e^{-i\omega x} \, dx \\
= \frac14 \omega^2 \operatorname{Im} \left(-i\pi \operatorname{sign}(\omega) \right)
= - \frac{\pi}{4} \omega^2 \operatorname{sign}(\omega)
.
$$

Thus,
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^3} \sin \omega x \, dx
= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left( - \frac{\pi}{4} \omega^2 \operatorname{sign}(\omega) \right)
= - \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4} \omega^2 \operatorname{sign}(\omega)
,
$$
which is the same as Mark Viola got.

---

### Sine transform in terms of Fourier transform

#### Functions

Let the Fourier transform on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be defined by
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f\} := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, e^{-i\xi x} \, dx
$$
and the sine transform on $L^1(0, \infty)$ be defined by
$$
\mathcal{Sine}\{f\} := \int_0^\infty f(x) \, \sin\xi x \, dx.
$$
Then,
$$\mathcal{Sine}\{f\} = \frac{i}{2} \mathcal{F}\{\bar{f}\},$$
where the *oddization* $\bar{f}$ of $f$ is defined by
$$
\bar{f}(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & (x>0) \\
-f(-x) & (x<0)
\end{cases}
$$

#### Distributions

Let $u \in \mathcal{S}'(0, \infty)$ have an odd extension $\bar{u} \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}).$ Then we define the sine transform of $u$ by
$$
\mathcal{Sine}\{u\} := \frac{i}{2} \mathcal{F}\{\bar{u}\}
$$

#### The case in the question

With $u = \frac{1}{x^3}$ and $\bar{u} = \frac12 \left(\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\right)''$ we get
$$
\mathcal{Sine}\{\frac{1}{x^3}\}
= \frac{i}{2} \mathcal{F}\{\frac12 \left(\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\right)''\}
= \frac{i}{2} \frac{1}{2} (i\xi)^2 \mathcal{F}\{\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\} \\
= \frac{i}{2} \frac{1}{2} i^2 \, \xi^2 (-i\pi \operatorname{sign}(\xi)) 
= -\frac{\pi}{4} \xi^2 \operatorname{sign}(\xi)
.
$$

Comment: I hope you're staying safe and healthy my friend. This development seems like formal manipulation in which the object $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x^3}\,dx$ is treated as an integral, although the integral diverges.  As you know, if the object is a distribution, it needs to act on a suitable test function. How does that work here?   I tried to regularize the distribution, but this led to the issues that we discussed yesterday.  And another user has asserted that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac1{x^3}1_{|x|\ge \varepsilon}$ fails to converge in distribution.  How can this be made rigorous?

Comment: Yes, it's first a formal manipulation to reach something that can be treated as a distributional Fourier transform. But the Fourier transform itself, $\mathcal{F}\{\frac 1 x\}=-i\pi\operatorname{sign}(\omega),$ is rigorous, although I still write it as an integral.

Comment: [Calculation of Fourier transform of $\operatorname{pv}\frac1x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2383887/168433)

Comment: [Earlier calculation of transform of $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2985405/168433)

Comment: Yes, of course I understand that the Fourier Transform of $1/x$ is well defined as a Cauchy principal value.

Comment: The formal calculations can probably be made rigorous by defining the sine transform of a distribution on $(0,\infty)$ in terms of the Fourier transform through extending the distribution to $(-\infty,\infty).$ The latter requires that the distribution is well-behaved at $0$.

Comment: @MarkViola. I added some more rigorous treatment defining sine transform in terms of Fourier transform and odd extension of the distribution (when such exists).

Comment: I've edited my answer considerably.  In particular, I am using a different regularization for $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x^3}\,dx$.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @MarkViola. Sure. Done.

Comment: And (+1) for the solid answer!  Well done.

Comment: @MarkViola. We complement each other.

Comment: Indeed.  The two answers arrive at the same conclusion using distinct approaches.  I'd be curious to see others.